# Prerender in angular could not export my routes that have parameter

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, prerender

I am trying to prerender my angular 7 app with **npm run build:prerender** but the main problem is that all my routes with parameters are not prerendered along side the other routes.. Please what can i do to make all my routes prerendered successfully

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `ng-toolkit/universal` here?

You can add routes to the file `static.paths.ts`:

```
export const ROUTES = [
  '/commits/yanxch'
];
```

whereas the route definition in my example is:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'commits/:username',
    component: CommitsView
  }
];
```

After running `npm run build:prerender` and `npm run serve:prerender` you should see the prerendered html source.

I've uploaded the example: https://github.com/yanxch/ssr-test